# where to put a general css in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm stuck, I don't know where to place my css file for the entire project application.

My project/app/Resources/views/base.html.twig looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}my app{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>
```

...
and my file is in:

project\app\Resources\public\css\main.css

But it never is loaded.

So, Where should I put the css file, and how to include it in my template?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the file to be at `project/web/css/main.css`

Comment: it's fine as it's an app level file

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html), documentation about asset management.

You probably have to execute the command :

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

`<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

without the trailing slash before css